# Column does not exist in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

I am trying to filter out days with more than 1% error rates for a website. I already have a table that shows the individual days with their respective error rates, but when I try to include a "where" or "having" clause to filter out the days with a ratio below .01, the query stops working and it says my column does not exist, even though I declared it a few characters before. 
This is the code:

```
select date(time) as day, 
    (trunc(cast(count(*) filter (where status similar to '%404%') as decimal) / count(*), 5)) as col1 
    from log
    where col1 > 0.01 
    group by day 
    order by col1 desc;
```

This is the error i get

```
ERROR:  column "col1" does not exist
LINE 4: where col1 > 0.01
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Change the `where` to `having`.

Comment: I have already tried changing the `where` to  a `having` and placing it after the group by but I get the same error @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 3):

`col1` is the result of an aggregation.  Postgres allows aliases for columns in the `group by`, but not `having`.  So move the condition to a `having` clause:

```
select date(time) as day, 
      (trunc(cast(count(*) filter (where status similar to '%404%') as decimal) / count(*), 5)) as col1 
from log
group by day 
having (trunc(cast(count(*) filter (where status similar to '%404%') as decimal) / count(*), 5)) > 0.01 
order by col1 desc;
```

Although `filter` is really fancy, I think this version of the logic is simpler:

```
      trunc(cast(avg( (status similar to '%404%')::decimal), 5) as col1
```

It is also easier to fit into the `having` clause.

Comment: I tried with having, but get the same result. (Col1 does not exist)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can't reference a column alias `col1` in a `WHERE` clause, unless you layer the query.

Repeated condition option:

```
select date(time) as day, 
       (trunc(cast(count(*) filter (where status similar to '%404%') as decimal) / count(*), 5)) as col1 
from log
group by day 
having (trunc(cast(count(*) filter (where status similar to '%404%') as decimal) / count(*), 5)) > 0.01
order by col1 desc;
```

Derived table option:

```
select day, col1
from (select date(time) as day, 
             (trunc(cast(count(*) filter (where status similar to '%404%') as decimal) / count(*), 5)) as col1 
      from log
      group by day) as derivedTable
where col1 > 0.01
```